# WWW загрузка трека

Tags: unity3d

Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for resource 0x0000000004A91520: , (Unsupported file or audio format. ),

```
clip = www.GetAudioClip(false, true, AudioType.OGGVORBIS);
```

трек ogg. в чем проблема? в инете везде пишут про эту ошибку, но не решение 
формат трека ogg. MP3 также пробовал формат и mp3 трек заливать, все пусто.